# How to change Jenkins output regarding to Test result?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using selenium webdriver 2.47.1 & TestNG for automation process. In my code I have 12 different tests & at end of each and every test I checked whether the test is pass or not using if else loop. sample code is given below..

```
@Test(priority = 0)
public void Login()  {
     String UserName = ex.getExcelValue(scenarioName, 2, 4);
     cd.findElement(By.xpath("//body/center/form/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(UserName);
     String PassWord = ex.getExcelValue(scenarioName, 3, 4);
     cd.findElement(By.xpath("//body/center/form/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(PassWord);
     cd.findElement(By.xpath("//body/center/form/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")).click();
     cd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     String ExpTitle = "Demo Practice";
     String ActTitle = cd.getTitle();
     if(ExpTitle.equals(ActTitle))   {
         ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 2, 8, "PASSED");
         System.out.println("PASSED : User Logged in Successfully");
     } else  {
         ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 2, 8, "FAILED");
         System.out.println("FAILED : User Not Logged in");
     }
}
```

I am using Jenkins for continuous integration. Now when I am running the above script Jenkins build successfully completed even the test is failed. How to change this?

Comment: why are you setting passed/failed in if else? why don't you use assertions?

Comment: I think `testng` Assertions work better here. That way you you would not have to worry about your Jenkins explicit setup. Assertions would make the tests to fail.

Comment: Do you think that using of assertions solve my issue..?

Comment: Unless your Jenkins build config is set to skip tests, which I highly doubt, Assertions will solve your problem here.

Comment: @Segmented. I will change if loop to Assertions & check it.. How to setup Jenkins to skip tests?

Comment: @Karthik I think you got confused on my comment. You would not need to set up Jenkins to skip tests. That kind of defeats the purpose of a continuous integration. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for can be handled this way. Use `testng` Assertions for your tests. That way your continuous integration environment can show your tests failing.

```
@Test
public void Login()  {
    String UserName = ex.getExcelValue(scenarioName, 2, 4);
    cd.findElement(By.xpath("//body/center/form/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(UserName);
    String PassWord = ex.getExcelValue(scenarioName, 3, 4);
    cd.findElement(By.xpath("//body/center/form/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(PassWord);
    cd.findElement(By.xpath("//body/center/form/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")).click();
    cd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String ExpTitle = "Demo Practice";
    String ActTitle = cd.getTitle();
    ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 2, 8, "FAILED");
    assertEquals(ActTitle, ExpTitle, "Expected: "+ExpTitle+" but found: "+ActTitle);
    ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 2, 8, "PASSED");

}
```

Few things, I think I would avoid:

- The use of `priority` in tests. Makes them dependant, you would not be able to make methods run in parallel
- Avoid `System.out.println()`. Assertions and Loggers are your friend here.

Comment: Your assertEquals should be the other way round, as testNG documentation states: `assertEquals(java.lang.String actual, java.lang.String expected) `. It is very confusing to be honest, because JUnit has this the other way around.

Comment: @Reins True! I made a stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing out. fixed it.

Comment: `String TesteNote1 = cd.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]")).getText();
    StringBuffer object1 = new StringBuffer(TesteNote1);
    String ActeNote1 = object1.substring(108);
    String ExpeNote1 = ex.getExcelValue(scenarioName, 75, 4);
    ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 75, 8, "FAILED");
     assertEquals(ActeNote1, ExpeNote1, "Expected: "+ExpeNote1+" but found: "+ActeNote1);
     ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 75, 8, "PASSED");` The result of the above test is FAIL. whenever I am running above script it gives result as PASS.. What is the mistake in above code??

Comment: @karthik Do you mean that the script is supposed to FAIL because of the difference of `ActeNote1` and `ExpeNote1` and yet execution asserts PASS?

Comment: @Karthik well the logic seems okay. it is hard to tell from just this code. You should try debugging and see how values of `ActeNote1` and `ExpeNote1` are changing before assertion. Btw, your original problem was different. You should accept an answer and open a new question for your new question.

Comment: @Segmented.. Sure man. I have TestNG assertions as you said.. See the answer that I have posted for this question. I used assertions inside try/finally block... Is this correct way?

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in a comment earlier, you should use assertions. Then you should not have the need to add any custom configuration to your jenkins build, as the tests would actually fail if the result is incorrect.

So instead of the if-else block, you should do:

```
assertEquals(ActTitle, ExpTitle);
```

Although there should be an **alternative**, if you really want to use your if-else, the testNG framework offers a fail() method. I haven't used it myself but if you change your if else block to this, it should also fail the jenkins build:

```
if(ExpTitle.equals(ActTitle))   {
         ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 2, 8, "PASSED");
         System.out.println("PASSED : User Logged in Successfully");
     } else  {
         ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 2, 8, "FAILED");
         fail("FAILED : User Not Logged in");
     }
}
```

More info on testng assertions: http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html

**I would recommend going with the first provided solution.**

Comment: fail() method didn't work... In my case out of 12 tests one test got failed, but jenkins result shows as all 12 tests passed.

Comment: Hi I used Assertions as you said `Assert.assertEquals(Expected, Actual);`. The test got failed & the execution stops there itself. I want to continue the execution after test failed also... How to do that>

Comment: @Karthik If this is not too late to reply. `Assertions` are designed to stop execution of tests when they fail. Perhaps you can adjust your logic around it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used try/finally block like below... It solved my issue

```
try {
      Assert.assertEquals(ExpeNote1, ActeNote1);
       ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 75, 8, "PASSED");
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
       ex.setExcelValue(scenarioName, 75, 8, "FAILED");
   }finally{
       cd.switchTo().defaultContent();}
```

Comment: I am glad you found a solution. It is not a good practice to code within a catch block. It leads to unnecessary problems in production. For example, if an exception is thrown in the code you just simply make the test case to fail without even looking into why the exception was thrown. Just a suggestion ;)